# Difference in execution times between caret and randomForest (even with method = "none")

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, caret

I have a dataset with 1205 observations and 285 predictors (all but one categorical). It is a binary classification task.

- When I run randomForest, it executes in less than 1 second.
- When I run caret with `method = "none"` in trControl, it executes in 81 seconds
- When I run caret with `method = "boot"` in trControl (`number = 1`), it executes in 158 seconds

So what is being done extra in caret that makes such a big difference in execution times? Note that I included `method = "none"`, which I think is supposed to prevent resampling. (I even looked in the caret source code...)

Here is my code:

```
rfControl <- trainControl(method = "boot", number = 1, repeats = 1)
rfControl2 <- trainControl(method = "none", number = 1, repeats = 1)
rfGrid <- expand.grid(mtry = c(16))

system.time( train( labelidx ~ ., data = t, method = "rf", ntree = 100, 
                    trControl = rfControl2, tuneGrid = rfGrid))

library(randomForest)
system.time( randomForest(labelidx ~ ., data = t, ntree = 100, mtry = 16))
```

and here are the results, pasted from rstudio:

```
> system.time( train( labelidx ~ ., data = t, method = "rf", ntree = 100, 
+                     trControl = rfControl, tuneGrid = rfGrid))
   user  system elapsed 
158.203   0.039 158.299 
> system.time( train( labelidx ~ ., data = t, method = "rf", ntree = 100, 
+                     trControl = rfControl2, tuneGrid = rfGrid))
   user  system elapsed 
 81.385   0.012  81.442 
> c(rfControl$method, rfControl$number, rfControl$repeats)
    [1] "boot" "1"    "1"   
    > c(rfControl2$method, rfControl2$number, rfControl2$repeats)
[1] "none" "1"    "1"   
> rfGrid
  mtry
1   16
> c(nrow(t), ncol(t))
[1] 1205  286

> system.time( randomForest(labelidx ~ ., data = t, ntree = 100, mtry = 16))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.354   0.000   0.354
```

Comment: This post should probably be migrated over to StackOverflow.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you included a reproducible example.